# Can I create an iPython notebook using JavaScript as the language in the cells?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I love IPython to explain algorithms in python. But I want to do the same using javascript. Is it possible to write a notebook where I use javascript as the cell language?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `%%javascript` magic function for running javascript in IPython notebook. For example Paste the following code in a IPython cell and run it. You should see the output in your browser's javascript console.

```
%%javascript
console.log("Hello World!")
```

For global variables, you can add an attribute to the `windows` object for 
example, in a cell run the following code:

```
%%javascript
window.myvar = 12;
```

In another cell, run the following code and check browser's javascript console. The variable's value should be printed.

```
%%javascript
console.log(myvar)
```

Use the `element` variable for printing in the cell output area as shown below:

```
%%javascript
element.append(myvar)
```

Comment: Not quote, because that is not building context between sessions. If I assign a variable in one cell,I cannot access it in the next cell.

Comment: much better! -- all I need is a way to get the result printed in the cell. Like python `print` or `sys.stdout.write`

Comment: @Michael_Scharf: Check out the last example.

Comment: See http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/minrk/5632595 for in browser js kernel, http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/Carreau/4279371/node-kernel.ipynb for an example of node.js kernel.